# C++ String to byte error

Tags: c++, arrays, string, copy

So, I converted the string to byte in C++, but when it goes to add it into registry, it's stripping off the exe part but keeping the ., I have no idea what's wrong with it.

If you're wondering what NXS is, the value of it is "noerrorsplease.exe", type is char.

```
char szFinal[] = "";
strcat(szFinal, (const char *)ExtractDirectory(filepath).c_str());
//Not needed: strcat(szFinal, "");
strcat(szFinal, nxs);
strcat(szFinal, ".exe");

        CString str;
        str = szFinal;
        str += ".exe";
        cout << str.GetString() << endl;
        const BYTE* pb = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(str.GetString());
        cout << pb << endl;
        DWORD pathLenInBytes = *szFinal * sizeof(*szFinal);
        if(RegSetValueEx(newValue, TEXT("Printing Device"), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)pb, pathLenInBytes) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            RegCloseKey(newValue);
            cout << "error" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Possibly worked." << endl;
        RegCloseKey(newValue);
```

Comment: Oh, I fixed my own mistake, duh. It was staring me right in the face! lol

Comment: had to replace the code to this for the dword pathleninbytes: DWORD pathLenInBytes = *str * sizeof(*str);

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
char szFinal[] = "";
strcat(szFinal, (const char *)ExtractDirectory(filepath).c_str());
```

is already invalid. You defined array szFina having only one character that is the terminating zero. You may not use it for copying in it any string. In these situations you should use an object of type std::string.

Comment: +1 There is *one* string you can concatenate, but it is rather boring (`""`). Regardless, this is still a serious problem and should be addressed.

Comment: Yep, I noticed my own error almost 10 minutes after posting it.